# Resource Images in Silverlight Not Consistently Showing

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I am having a really frustrating time with having "Resource" images in my Silverlight application.  I am using the Telerik controls, however I am seeing the same issue with the standard Image element.  I have two images in the same folder, both set to "Resource".  I have extracted the .dll out of the .xap and verified that the images are being embedded, and they are.  However one of the images will show and one will not.  Here is the XAML that is causing the issue:

```
<telerik:RadRibbonButton x:Name="AddToDashboardButton"
                                             Text="Add To Dashboard" 
                                             SplitText="True"
                                             Size="Large"
                                             LargeImage="/Nucleus.Application;component/Themes/Images/32/AddToDashboard.png"/>
                    <telerik:RadRibbonButton x:Name="PublishButton"
                                             Text="Publish"
                                             Size="Large"
                                             LargeImage="/Nucleus.Application;component/Themes/Images/32/Publish.png" />
```

If I used Fiddler to watch the HTTP traffic I notice that the first image gets an external Http request while the second one does not.  So it appears to be grabbing the second one just find, but not the first!?!?  Why not! What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: is there anything special about these pngs?

Comment: Does the broken image load if you swap the LargeImage attributes or remove the SplitText attribute?